# Add post data to url

Tags: magento-1.9, php

I have my basic product listing, which redirects to the product view page like this: `<a href="<?php echo $_product->getProductUrl() ?>">` Now I want to add my own variable to the url but I have no idea how to achieve that.

I've tried just simply adding `?value=value` but it returns errors

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cant add a POST parameter to an URL. What you can do is add a GET parameter to the url like this:

```
<a href="<?php echo $_product->getProductUrl() ?>/name_of_param/value">Link</a>
```

and retrieve it afterwards with

```
$this->getRequest()->getParam('name_of_param');
```

Comment: To slightly expand on the above, if you need to send POST data you will need to do something like submit a form or make an AJAX request.

Comment: @JonathanHussey i'm making an AJAX request. but if im working in `list.phtml` and want to post the data to `list.phtml` i'm not sure what url to refer to

Comment: If the request you are making results in the `list.phtml` template rendering then you can pull the POST param with `Mage::app()->getRequest()->getPost()` to pull POST data sent with the request.

Answer (score 0):

You can directly append value to function like...

```
 <a href="<?php echo $_product->getProductUrl().'/param1/value1/param2/value2' ?>">Product Link</a>
```

Fetch value from controller like this,

```
  $this->getRequest()->getParam('param1');
  $this->getRequest()->getParam('param2');
```